# VBA Excel Removing duplicate rows

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to remove any rows that have a duplicate in column C. This is a column of about 700 records however this value varies with different data used hence I've implemented a "LastRow" function. Here's my code:

```
Public Function LastRowInCRC() As Long

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")

    With wsCRC
        LastRowInCRC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Function

Sub DeleteDupRowsCRC()

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")

    Dim lrowcrc As Long
    lrowcrc = CRC.LastRowInCRC

    'Debug.Print "C8:C" & lrowcrc

    With wsCRC

        .Range("C8:C" & lrowcrc).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3)

    End With

End Sub
```

I get the "application-defined or object-defined" error at the following line when I step by step debug:

```
.Range("C8:C" & lrowcrc).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3)
```

Any ideas whats going wrong? I call the "C8:C" & lrowcrc to the immediate window which is commented out, and it gives me the correct range values so I don't think the issue is in that but I cannot find whats wrong... any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, change `Array(3)` to `Array(1)` and it may work.

---

Not general: The following works for me, removing the duplicates in column `C` Make sure that you work on the first Worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LastRowInCRC() As Long

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Set wsCRC = Worksheets(1)

    With wsCRC
        LastRowInCRC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

End Function

Sub DeleteDupRowsCRC()

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Set wsCRC = Worksheets(1)

    Dim lrowcrc As Long
    lrowcrc = LastRowInCRC

    'Debug.Print "C8:C" & lrowcrc

    With wsCRC

        .Range("C1:C" & lrowcrc).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

    End With

End Sub
```

In your code, `Array(3)` means that you should have at least three column in the `.Range`. But you only have column `C` there. Thus, it gives mistake. To work with `Array(3)`, Write `A1:C` and it would be working.

Answer (score 1):

I think your range Invalid syntax.
Please, try this below

```
With wsCRC
    .Range(Cells(8, 3), Cells(lrowcrc, 3)).Select
    .Range(Cells(8, 3), Cells(lrowcrc, 3)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End With
```

Beside, I think you should using below

> lrowcrc = LastRowInCRC

Or using this code to get last row

> wsCRC.[C8].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row